# Match and replace a specific underscore to tab in shell

Tags: regex, string, shell

I want to replace a specific underscore from a file and replace it with a tab. The problem is that I have a lot of underscores and when I try with tr all the underscores are replaced by tabs. Here's an example of the format of the file:

```
Arabidopsis_thaliana_TRANSCRIPT_NM1000_c5_g4_i1
Arabidopsis_thaliana_TRANSCRIPT_NM2530_c1_g1_i1
Arabidopsis_lyrata_TRANSCRIPT_NM10000_c2_g2_i2
Oriza_sativa_TRANSCRIPT_NM43000_c1_g2_i4
Oriza_sativa_TRANSCRIPT_NM31000_c2_g1_i1
```

The output that I want is the following:

```
Arabidopsis_thaliana    TRANSCRIPT_NM1000_c5_g4_i1
Arabidopsis_thaliana    TRANSCRIPT_NM2530_c1_g1_i1
Arabidopsis_lyrata     TRANSCRIPT_NM10000_c2_g2_i2
Oriza_sativa     TRANSCRIPT_NM43000_c1_g2_i4
Oriza_sativa     TRANSCRIPT_NM31000_c2_g1_i1
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Best.

Comment: If TRANSCRIPT occurs in every line then match with `_TRANSCRIPT`. If it does not you need to find a different pattern which all your lines will satisfy like the second underscore or something. Also show the actual code where  you are doing the replacement so we can understand the context better.

Comment: Yes, TRANSCRIPT occurs in every line. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`. If your text is in `test.txt`, then try this:

```
$ sed -i.bak "s/_TRANSCRIPT/$(echo '\t')TRANSCRIPT/g" test.txt
```

Comment: @user18081990 Cheers, glad to help.